# How to create a Gtk3 Entry in Python not editable but receive Drag and Drop?

Tags: python, gtk3

I created a [Gtk.Entry](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/Entry.html) with [Drag and Drop](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gdk-3.0/flags.html#Gdk.DragAction) function. This entry is able to receive text data from Drag and Drop.
But change text by hand should not be allowed, so I set editable to False.

Now Drag and Drop is no longer working. Method "on_drag_data_received" is no longer called.
Searching for a solution...

```
class DragDropEntry(Gtk.Entry):

    def __init__(self, placeholder_text="drop something here", editable=False):
        Gtk.Entry.__init__(self, placeholder_text=placeholder_text, editable=editable)
        self.drag_dest_set(Gtk.DestDefaults.ALL, [], DRAG_ACTION)
        self.connect("drag-data-received", self.on_drag_data_received)
        self.drag_dest_add_text_targets()

    def on_drag_data_received(self, widget, drag_context, x, y, data, info, time):
        uri = data.get_data().strip('\r\n\x00')
        uri_splitted = uri.split() # we may have more than one file dropped
        for uri in uri_splitted:
            path = self.get_file_path_from_dnd_dropped_uri(uri)
            self.set_text(path)
            return

    def get_file_path_from_dnd_dropped_uri(self, uri):
        path = ""
        if uri.startswith('file:\\\\\\'): # windows
            path = uri[8:] # 8 is len('file:///')
        elif uri.startswith('file://'): # nautilus, rox
            path = uri[7:] # 7 is len('file://')
        elif uri.startswith('file:'): # xffm
            path = uri[5:] # 5 is len('file:')
        path = urllib.url2pathname(path) # escape special chars
        path = path.strip('\r\n\x00') # remove \r\n and NULL
        return path
```